# Show all posts in database on homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a website. I want to show all the posts from all users. But I got the following error message:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #3):

\app\view\static_pages\home.html.erb:

```
   <div class="span8">    
     <ul class="microposts">
       <% @microposts.each do |micropost| %>
         <li>
           micropost.content
         </li>
```

and I've already defined in the 
\app\controller\static_pages_controller.rb:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    if signed_in?
      @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end

  def index
    @microposts = Micropost.all
  end
end
```

What's missing? I have 310 sample posts in the database already...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What page are you trying to show posts on? If that's `home`, then you should modify your `home` action to load all posts:

```
def home
  if signed_in?
    @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
    @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  @microposts = Micropost.all
end
```

Maybe it was the `@feed_items` you wanted to display on the `home` page?

Comment: Thanks man, define the @microposts inside home definitely helps!!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating @microposts instance variable in home view but you have defined @micropost in your home action. This is wrong that you are doing.

You need to define @microposts instance variable in home view so you will get all posts on page.